# Setting up a Menu for Code Generation in VSCode

Tags: rascal

How can I create a menu in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) to facilitate code generation? Are there any recommended sources or code repositories that provide examples or guidance on implementing this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VScode is not a "menu" driven user-interface. So typically there are other ways of interaction. The best thing is to register a "command", such it will appear in the Command Palette.

From Rascal the most easy-to-use feature for registering commands is to insert `lenses` into the editor for the DSL. If you click on such a lense a command will be activated that you can handle in Rascal directly.

There is a demo [here](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Packages/RascalLsp/API/demo/lang/pico/LanguageServer/)

But it amounts to registering lenses and the executors:

```
// extend the set of possible commands, with possible parameters:
data Command  = doSomething(start[Program] program);

// detect places to put lenses:
rel[loc,Command] myLenses(start[Program] input) 
  = {<input@\loc, doSomething(input /* any parameter to the command */, title="This is what the user sees!")>};

// a command handler:
value myCommandHandler(doSomething(start[Program] input)) {
    ... do anything here, possible using features from util::IDEServices...
    return ("result": true);
}
```

And those `myCommandHandler` and `myLenses` functions would be registered with the language as `Contribution`s.

If the code generator adds code to existing files, it makes sense to use `util::IDEServices::registerDocumentEdits`, because that will integrate with open editors and the undo stack. Otherwise you can just write files to disk using the `IO` module (`writeFile`)